# jQuery difference for slider on Chrome, Firefox, and IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This is a general question on how to debug browser specific quirks.

I have a site:
http://calpolyaias.com/portfolio/scalar-duality#

This is the code that runs the slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init_jquery_swipe(){
        /*If there are no slides, hide slider*/
        if(!jQuery(".project-slider").find("li").length){
            jQuery(".project-slider").hide();
            return true;
        }
        /*If there are no slides, hide slider*/

        jQuery(".project-slider,.project-slider *").removeAttr("style");

        var projectWidth = jQuery('.project-content-top').width();
        jQuery('.project-slider ul li').css('width', projectWidth); /*KV CHANGED*/

        /*var imagesHeight = jQuery('.project-slider ul li').find('img').height();
        jQuery('.project-slider').css('height', imagesHeight);*/
        var img_height = [];
        jQuery('.project-slider ul li').find('img').each(function(el){
            img_height.push(parseInt(jQuery(this).height()));
        });
        img_height = Math.min.apply(null,img_height);
        //jQuery('.project-slider').css('height', img_height+"px");

        var slideWidth = jQuery('.project-slider ul li').width();
        var currentSlide = 0;
        var maxSlides =  jQuery('.project-slider ul li').length;
        var speed = 500;

        var slides;
        slides = jQuery(".project-slider ul");
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            slides.swipe( {
                triggerOnTouchEnd : true,
                swipeStatus : swipeStatus,
                allowPageScroll:"vertical",
                threshold:75
            } );
            jQuery(".slider-arrows").hide();
        }

        function swipeStatus(event, phase, direction, distance) {
            if( phase=="move" && (direction=="left" || direction=="right") )
            {
                if(direction=="left" || direction=="right"){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                var duration=0;

                if (direction == "left")
                    scrollImages((slideWidth * currentSlide) + distance, duration);

                else if (direction == "right")
                    scrollImages((slideWidth * currentSlide) - distance, duration);

            }

            else if ( phase == "cancel")
            {
                scrollImages(slideWidth * currentSlide, speed);
            }

            else if ( phase =="end" )
            {
                if (direction == "right")
                    previousImage()
                else if (direction == "left")
                    nextImage()
            }
        }

        function previousImage()
        {
            currentSlide = Math.max(currentSlide-1, 0);
            scrollImages( slideWidth * currentSlide, speed);
            jQuery('.project-slider ul li').eq(currentSlide).find('img').css('opacity', 1);
            jQuery('.project-slider ul li').eq(currentSlide).next().find('img').css('opacity', 0.3);
        }

        function nextImage()
        {
            currentSlide = Math.min(currentSlide+1, maxSlides-1);
            scrollImages( slideWidth * currentSlide, speed);
            //jQuery('.project-slider ul li').eq(currentSlide).next().find('img').css('opacity', 1);
            jQuery('.project-slider ul li').eq(currentSlide).find('img').css('opacity', 1);
            jQuery('.project-slider ul li').eq(currentSlide).prev().find('img').css('opacity', 0.3);
        }

        function scrollImages(distance, duration){

            slides.css("-webkit-transition-duration", (duration/1000).toFixed(1) + "s");
            slides.css("-moz-transition-duration", (duration/1000).toFixed(1) + "s");
            slides.css("-o-transition-duration", (duration/1000).toFixed(1) + "s");
            slides.css("-ms-transition-duration", (duration/1000).toFixed(1) + "s");

            var value = (distance<0 ? "" : "-") + Math.abs(distance).toString();
            slides.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d("+value +"px,0px,0px)");
            slides.css("-moz-transform", "translate3d("+value +"px,0px,0px)");
            slides.css("-o-transform", "translate3d("+value +"px,0px,0px)");
            slides.css("-ms-transform", "translate3d("+value +"px,0px,0px)");
            if(!Modernizr.csstransforms3d){
                jQuery(".slider-holder").scrollLeft(Math.abs(value));
            }
        }

        /*var projectWidth = jQuery('.project-content-top').width();
        jQuery('.project-slider ul li').css('width', projectWidth);
        jQuery('.project-slider ul li').css('height', img_height - 65);

        jQuery('.project-slider').css('height', img_height);
        jQuery('.slider-holder').css('height', img_height - 65);*/

        var sliderImgHeight = jQuery('.project-slider').height();
        //jQuery('.project-slider ul').find('li iframe').css('height', sliderImgHeight);
        //jQuery('.slider-holder .slider-arrows a.next-slide').css('left', 500px); /*KV */ 
        //window.alert(jQuery('.slider-holder .slider-arrows a.next-slide').css('left'));

        jQuery('body').on('click', '.slider-arrows a.next-slide', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            nextImage();
        });

        jQuery('.slider-holder').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            nextImage();
        });



        jQuery('body').on('click', '.slider-arrows a.prev-slide', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           previousImage();
        });

        jQuery('.project-slider ul li img').imgscale({
            scale : 'fit',
            center : true
        });
        center_image();
        function center_image(){
            jQuery('.project-slider ul li').find('img').each(function(){
                var this_img = jQuery(this);

                var parent_width = parseInt(this_img.parent().width() / 2);
                var this_img_width = parseInt(this_img.width() / 2);

                var parent_height = parseInt(this_img.parent().height() / 2);
                var this_img_height = parseInt(this_img.height() / 2);

                this_img.css("margin-left",(parent_width - this_img_width) + "px");
                this_img.css("margin-top",(parent_height - this_img_height) + "px");
            });
        }
    }

    jQuery('#inner-content').waitForImages( function() {
        jQuery(".project-slider ul").swipe("destroy");
        init_jquery_swipe();
        jQuery("a[rel='fancybox_gallery']").fancybox();
    });

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        jQuery(".project-slider ul").swipe("destroy");
        init_jquery_swipe();
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.accordion li:first-child').find('a').addClass('active').find('i').removeClass('icon-plus-sign').addClass('icon-minus-sign');
        $('.accordion li:first-child').find('.section_content').show();

        $('.tabs .tab_buttons > li:first-child').find('a').addClass('active');
        $('.tabs .tab_content li:first-child').show();
    });


</script>
```

On Chrome, the images from the slider disappear while the slider works perfectly on IE and Firefox.

What are the known difference for chrome and how it treats jQuery-- where do I start looking?

In general, what is a good procedure for me to follow to nail this one and bugs like it?

Something interesting is that changing the window size (opening developer tools in chrome) seems to stop the problem however.

The wordpress theme is called NORDIC if you want to try pinning down the difference between this site and the original template...

Comment: I think your problem is in the CSS, not in jQuery... Can you remove the `width: auto` from the `.project-slider ul li img` and try?

Comment: hmm.. changed that =/ still no avail, thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: changing the window size (opening developer tools in chrome) seems to stop the problem however.

Comment: Strange. Which Chrome version you have? Earlier versions was launched with big CSS problems (early february).

Comment: tested on a couple. personally testing on chromium. 40.0.2214.115 (303346) • Thursday, 19 Feb 2015

Comment: This is pretty interesting -- works on safari as well, another webkit browser, but not chrome. Literally works on everything besides chrome!

Comment: Really interesting... everything I change, remove or add in Developer Tools seem to fix it. Maybe it's an `onload` bug. Do you have another custom scripts which has onload actions?

Comment: so many things show up when I do a string search =/ nothing shows up in the php document which is used to generate the page tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove this:

```
transition: opacity .5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
```

from `.project-slider ul li img`.

or Try this:

```
transition: all .5s;
-webkit-transition: all .5s;
```

Comment: just tried it =/ doesnt seem to be working. takes a while for the server to update tho, it has caching

Comment: removed the transitions... doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I am watching this updated css. While removing transition working now. Have you tested this?

Comment: oh i see! it works now. I added the transition with "all" and the problem comes back again. Any ideas on how to achieve the smooth transition? Thank you so much!

Comment: So just remove it @stackOverFlew. Don't add `all` also

Answer (score 0):

Try removing overflow hidden? from your CSS for: `.project-slider ul li`
When I remove that, it seems to work fine.

Comment: just changed it... seems to be the same. Not sure if server updated cache yet. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: if you open developer tools in chrome the problem is fixed automatically.